# What is the correct way of handling memory for thumbnail images in UITableViewCells?

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory-management

**Short Explanation**

Currently I have a `UITableView` which contains cells of videos from a website. In addition each cell (which represents a video) has a specific thumbnail image. These images are downloaded asynchrounously using `NSURLConnection` (so I do not have to worry about threading myself). When these image objects have downloaded they simply notify the `UITableView` to refresh the cell it belongs to.

**My Problem**

As standard there will be fetched 10 new videos to the `UITableView` each call. This means that the user is allowed to push a cell at the bottom of the `UITableView` to request 10 new videos and so forth. The problem here is that there will quickly be a whole lot of memory usage because data for all thumbnail images (in the `UITableView`) will still exists no matter what.

Is there a smart way in which you can de-allocate image objects that aren't currently in the view?

Also, the `UITableView` simply renders all its cells directly from an array I have of all video objects ever fetched from the website. This means there is no limits as to how many times the user can request new videos, making this array bigger and bigger all the time. Is it correct to keep these kind of arrays in memory all the time? Or should you instead delete the ones which goes out of the view and request them again later on?